# Hovering over one's own up-vote or down-vote should show when it was cast

Tags: feature-request, voting

I have come across some questions recently where I saw that I up-voted either the question, an answer or both, like this one - [Sort array by firstname (alphabetically) in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712034/sort-array-by-firstname-alphabetically-in-javascript), and out of curiosity I have wanted to know when I did so.

I think it would be nice if hovering over the up-vote or down-vote showed that information. It is possible to find out via the votes tab in one's profile but it's not that easy when there are many of them.

Comment: Just a temporary work-around for now, if the post has not been edited since you have voted on it and it has been more than 5 minutes it will notify you of when you last voted (along with telling you that you cannot change your vote until the post gets edited)

Comment: @TinyGiant: And, of course, if it's been less than five minutes since you voted, you should certainly be able to remember that ;)

Comment: @Nathan What, those suffering from Alzheimer's disease or Dementia can't be Stack Overflow users?

Comment: @TinyGiant: I suspect they will face very many far more serious problems with that that are, if anything, insoluble by SE.

Comment: @Nathan I didn't say it would be rational.

Comment: "Nice if" => "Nice to have" (i.e. probably won't get done), but agree it's not easy to search your old votes which can be annoying.